# Chess, but with gravity? #1

Tags: optimization, chess

<sub>Based off of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121536/gravity-chess-slipping-through-the-cracks) puzzle and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1Cw83Jn-q8) Youtube video</sub>

Rules:

- You control the pieces labeled `kn` (knight), `b` (bishop), and `r` (rook)
- You are trying to capture the piece labeled `ok` (opponent king)
- Walls can be jumped over by knights, and floors can be passed through in any direction by any piece but cannot be fallen through.
- If a piece hits the `ok`, it is captured.
- Pieces fall until they are blocked by a wall, a floor, or a piece of the same color.
- `ok` cannot move.
- Walls and floors can be passed through by `kn`.

The puzzle:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | x |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | x | x | x |   |   |   | x |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | x |kn | x |   |   | x |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | x |   | x |   | x |   |ok |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | x |   |   | x |   | x |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| b | x |   |   | x |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| r |   |   | x |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

[image]

Now my question to you is:

### What is the minimum number of moves needed to capture the opponent's king?

Comment: For an online game based on this, see this game in Armor Games: https://armorgames.com/chessformer-game/19096

Comment: "If a piece hits the `ok`, it is captured." - which is captured, the piece or the `ok`?

Comment: can the rook and bishop also pass through black squares? - on a normal chess-board one would think so ?

Comment: @Falco no, they can’t (due to gravity)

Comment: Ok - so the black squares block movement for rook and bishop completely? They can not pass through them in any way? That should be stated in the question - gravity only pulls items downward, it is not stated that black squares are walls.

Comment: This looks like a very nice concept allowing for quite complicated puzzles but your particular setup actually requires only one of the three figures to move and doesn't use features like figures being able to support each other.

Comment: @quarague I was expecting at least the bishop and knight to support each other (7 moves) but it turned out it could be done just using the bishop

Comment: Since the question you took inspiration from has very well worded rules, you should probably copy the rules-text of the original question to your own question. It includes all rules for walls blocking movement and also about units supporting each other, which this question is currently missing.

Comment: @psmears `ok` would be captured

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minumum number of moves appears to be

> Four

> [image: four moves]

Comment: whoops lol, intended it to be 7 but lol

Comment: This is assuming of course that the rook cannot move through black squares (which I think is intended but not specifically stated).

Comment: @hexomino That's what's intended (due to gravity)

Comment: @CrSb0001 I mean move sideways through them, for example, so rook could go all the way over and then up.

Comment: @hexomino Rooks can't jump onto a block (due to chess rules)

Comment: @CrSb0001 I think you misunderstand me, in chess parlance the moves would be Rh1 and then Rh4, no jumping.

Comment: @hexomino nope, the rook would just fall back down to Rh1

Comment: It should have been stated, but the black squares are walls that cannot be entered or passed through. The knight can jump over the walls per standard knight movement. @hexomino

Comment: @DanielMathias it is stated (bullet point 3) but I think it must've gotten lost in meaning due to horrible wording.

Comment: @CrSb0001 Bullet point 3 only describes the effect of gravity after a move is made.

Comment: @DanielMathias it literally says "unless there is a black square under them [the piece]", so no, it is stated.

Comment: @CrSb0001 It says "unless [conditions], [effect of gravity]" Please refer to my previous comment on what should be stated.

Comment: @CrSb0001 what's your intended 7-step solution?

Comment: @justhalf Probably Bb1 Be4=e3 Bg1 Ne7=e6 Nf8=f6 Ng4=g2 Nxh4

Comment: Ah, probably. It's nice that OP could've just blocked off e1 if they want to use this puzzle somewhere else with the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

## The minimum is

> 3

> 1. Knight to E5 (2 right, 1 down) -> falls down to E3
>
> 2. Knight to F5 (2 up, 1 right) -> keeps standing, black underneath
>
> 3. Knight to H4 (2 right, 1 down)

This assumes that the knight can land on black squares (not forbidden by the rules) and gravity cares only if a black field is below the knight.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this more clear. A knight can pass through black squares, but  it can't go on the same square as a black square (due to gravity)