# Chess with gravity #2: Keys, Locks, and Lava

Tags: optimization, chess

<sub>[<kbd>Previous Puzzle</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123593/chess-but-with-gravity-1)</sub>

---

<sub>If you're having trouble understanding the key/lock thing, watch [this](https://youtu.be/y1Cw83Jn-q8?si=6V-0RdGQ0WidfEkT&t=533) until 9:30 which might be a better explanation of what I'm trying to say</sub>

General Rules:

- In this puzzle, you control `kn` (knight) and `r` (rook)
- You are trying to capture `ok` (opponent's king)
- If one of your pieces touches `ok`, `ok` is captured.
- Walls can be jumped over by knights, and floors can be passed through in any direction by any piece but cannot be fallen through.
- Pieces fall until they are blocked by a wall, floor, or a piece that you control.
- Walls and floors can be passed through by `kn`.
- Gravity affects all pieces including `ok`.

New gimmick ruleset:

1. Lock

> - A lock (represented by `l`) cannot be passed through by any piece. It requires a piece that you control to touch something labeled `ke` (key), and then ***all squares labeled `l` will disappear.***

2. Key

> - A key (represented by `ke`) is what is required to get rid of locks. However, say we have this situation:
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+
> |   |ke |   |
> +---+---+---+
> |kn | l | l |
> +---+---+---+
> | l |   |   |
> +---+---+---+
> ```
>
> Here we have a knight at R2C1. Since no piece can pass through a lock in any direction, the only place the knight can go is R1C3. However, it isn't going to pick up the key. This is basically because the knight "teleports" to R1C3.
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+
> |   |ke |kn |
> +---+---+---+
> |   | l | l |
> +---+---+---+
> | l |   |   |
> +---+---+---+
> ```
>
> *The same can be said for the rook and queen (`q`): (`r/q` means "rook or queen")
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+          +---+---+---+
> |r/q|ke |   |    1     |   |ke |r/q|
> +---+---+---+   -->    +---+---+---+
> | l | l | l |   move   | l | l | l |
> +---+---+---+          +---+---+---+
> ```
>
> and the bishop
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+          +---+---+---+
> |   |   |   |    1     |   |   | b |
> +---+---+---+   move   +---+---+---+
> |   |ke | l |    ->    |   |ke | l |
> +---+---+---+          +---+---+---+
> | b |   | l |          |   |   | l |
> +---+---+---+          +---+---+---+
> ```
>
> However, concerning gravity:
>
> - If a piece is being affected by gravity and there is at least one cell between where said piece starts falling and where it lands (whether it be on a black square, lock, other piece, or disintegrated by lava) that contains `ke`, then the key(s) will be counted as being picked up and all squares represented by `l` will disappear.

3. Lava

> - No piece can pass through lava. (in text versions, this will be represented by `lav`)
> - Lava automatically disintegrates any piece that it touches. (the piece that touches the lava is removed from the board)

The puzzle:

[image]

Now my question to you is:

### What is the minimum number of moves needed to capture `ok`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 moves

> Knight moves: RDDf1, RRDf1, URR, RRD(Uf2 also works), UUR, RRDf1(Uf3 also works), RRUf1. This is the quickest the knight can possibly move far enough right, as column 5 doesn't contain a lock. This is then followed by rook to column 4 or 5, falling into a key and then into lava, while the opposing king falls onto the knight.

Basically, the rook can only grab a key, and doing so will drop the opposing king on the only surviving land, where our knight must already be.